# Nuget package missing interfaces

Tags: nuget

I have created a package for a framework which depends on numerous projects within a single solution. I want to create nuget packages for the framework and various projects within the solution.

In Framework.Framework.nuspec, I have the following dependencies declared:

```
    <dependencies>
        <group>
            <dependency id="Framework.CompositionRoot" version="1.0" />
            <dependency id="Framework.Services" version="1.0" />
            <dependency id="Framework.Domain" version="1.0" />                              
        </group>
    </dependencies>
```

And in each project file has its own nuspec file, such as Framework.CompositionRoot.nuspec, which has the following dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <group>
            <dependency id="Super.Services" version="1.0" />
            <dependency id="Super.Data" version="1.0" />
            <dependency id="Super.Domain" version="1.0" />                              
        </group>
    </dependencies>
```

My problem is that when I install Framework.Framework in another project, it seems to install some of the dependent nuget packages but not others. In this case, it installs Framework.CompositionRoot and Framework.Services, but not Framework.Domain.

Framework.Domain has its own nuspec file in the solution and the generated Framework.Framework.nupkg file shows Framework.Domain as a dependency. I have only installed Framework.Framework in the project, not Framework.Domain, since to my understanding this should be installed when I install Framework.Framework.

When I look in the references for the solution, it has added a Framework.Domain.dll, but half of the interfaces declared in that domain are missing. (I have made sure the missing interfaces are declared as public.) However, if I copy/paste the dll into the lib folder and reference it manually, all the of the interfaces are there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to nuget installing old versions by default. While Framework.Domain was not in the list of installed packages when viewing through the package manager, it was visible in packages.config, and had an old version which did not contain the interfaces. (Nuget install will install the lowest version of dependencies by default.)

In order to fix this, I uninstalled the package and re-installed it using the flag:

-DependencyVersion "HighestPatch".